# Why 'adb shell screenrecord' in android makes an empty file?

Tags: android, adb, screen-recording

I'm trying to record my mobile phone's screen using adb shell command.
When the command is executed in the terminal(PC), recording works well. But, in android studio, mp4 file is created but it is an **empty** file. Is there anybody who knows the reason?
Here is my code.

```
val cmd = arrayOf("screenrecord", "/path/name.mp4")

val builder = ProcessBuilder(*cmd)

builder.start()
```

ps. I already know I can use mediaprojection to record the screen of my phone. But I have a reason why I try to record using adb shell. So, please do not give me a comment about the mediaprojection.